# What is written in that big bracket?

Tags: meaning, etymology, hanja

[image: together]

I was looking up the Korean word for “together”, when I came across its entry in the pure Korean dictionary on my iPhone. There’s this big bracket which seems to provide the etymology of the word.

I recognise some Hanja; they possibly refer to old Korean texts which made use of this word. I also see a few obsolete hangul symbols, meaning that some Middle Korean is written in there too. However, I am a beginner in Korean and do not understand the meaning of the text.

What information does the bracket convey? In particular, what does the “square root” indicate?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there would be a legend of notations somewhere in the app, but not really sure so I'm writing this as a comment. From what I see, it seems like that sqrt refers to "root" of the word(etymology). The rest tells you how this word changed over time, giving examples w/citations.

Comment: "From root morpheme (√) 「⿳ㅎㆍㄴ」 (meaning **同一**, *one/unity*) + root morpheme 「⿰⿱⿲ㅂㅅㄱㅡㅣ 」 (meaning **時**, *time*)." Check out Naver's entry [here](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/70bc154b16914037a7a27fc44f0707d9).

Comment: @dROOOze my new question is, who mapped these hangul to these Chinese characters?

Comment: The dictionary maker. (I’m serious, this is not a *hun’dok* relationship with *Hanja*. The Naver entry shows that these *hangul* were described in the entry with native Korean words instead. It’s kind of like seeing differently worded definitions for the same word in different dictionaries.)...There might be a chance that there is a unified, industry standard set of brief *Hanja* terms which are used to academically translate Middle Korean roots, but I’m not a Korean linguist to be able to know such a fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the etymology of 함께. ㅎㆍㅁ must be 
[image: -], but most fonts do not fully support old Hangul characters.

---

√: root

[ ]: meaning (in Hanja) of the preceding character

→: word formation or synchronic change

>: diachronic change

( ): reference

---

月印 39: 其39 in "月印千江之曲 (1447)"

續三綱 忠 2: second case regarding 忠 in "續三綱行實圖 (1514)" (For [image: -], it should have been 孝 *not* 忠. [image] is in 續三綱 忠 2.)

飜老 上 23: Page 23 of the first volume of "飜譯老乞大 (1517)"

譯解 下 51: Page 51 of the second volume of "譯語類解 (1690)"

敬信 22: Page 22 of "敬信錄諺釋 (or 敬信錄諺解) (1796)"